# How to loop to copy data following blank cells in a column and paste it to last empty column?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy a block of data in column A (which are in between blank spaces) and paste it to last empty column.
Example: I have data in range A1:A18 and a blank cell, and again data in A20:A37 and 2 blank cells & and again data in A40:A57 & so on. I need to copy those data and paste in Column B, C, D....

The pattern of blank spaces is not uniform.

Screenshot of Excel File
[image]

I did some research on the internet and created a code to paste manually selected data in column A to the last empty column. But the list is too long and I want to automate the process.

I tried this code to find blank spaces and copy data. It finds the last blank row and copies all data, popping up an error.

```
Sub Pasting_Data_to_last_column()
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastCol As Long

Sheets("Input").Activate
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'finds the number of the last column
lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Copy

'paste the copied value to last empty column
Cells(1, lastCol + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

I believe this problem can be solved with a loop but I don't have any idea about that as I am new to VBA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, which uses SpecialCells to extract blocks of cells (or Areas). It assumes the cells do not contain formulae so if this is not the case, will need changing.

```
Sub x()

Dim r As Long

For r = 2 To Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas.Count
    Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas(r).Copy
    Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The code worked perfectly. I can't thank you enough for this code. It exactly solved my problem. Thank you once again!

Comment: My pleasure. Btw I suggest you change the procedure and variable names to more meaningful terms.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try this code. It is very flexible. You can adjust the four parameters at its top to the requirements of your environment.

```
Sub CopyToColumns()
    ' 02 Jan 2019

    ' Change these parameters to fit your requirements:-
    Const WsName As String = "TestSheet"
    Const SourceClm As String = "A"
    Const FirstRow As Long = 2                      ' applicable to all columns
    Const FirstTargetClm As String = "D"

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim InArr As Variant
    Dim OutArr As Variant, i As Long
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim C As Long
    Dim R As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WsName)
    If Err Then Exit Sub                            ' exit if the sheet doesn't exist
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Ws
        InArr = Range(.Cells(FirstRow, SourceClm), .Cells(.Rows.Count, SourceClm).End(xlUp)).Value
    End With
    C = Columns(FirstTargetClm).Column

    For R = 1 To UBound(InArr)
        If InArr(R, 1) <> "" Then
            i = 0
            ReDim OutArr(1 To UBound(InArr))
            Do
                i = i + 1
                OutArr(i) = InArr(R, 1)
                R = R + 1
                If R > UBound(InArr) Then Exit Do
            Loop While InArr(R, 1) <> ""
            If i Then
                ReDim Preserve OutArr(i)
                Set Rng = Cells(FirstRow, C).Resize(i)
                Rng.Value = Application.Transpose(OutArr)
                C = C + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next R
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code, I really appreciate your help, this code works well and its fast too. But how can I copy Formatting too? I want to copy both Values and number formats. I would be glad if you could help on this matter too. Thanks once again!

Comment: You have selected an answer to which I have personally awarded a bonus point because I think it's brilliant. Your question regarding my code seems to be in the category of a follow-up re an also-ran. If it's important to you give it a new question. Note that the speed comes from not copying formats. Depending upon what your exact problem is the code might be extended to apply formats to the new columns after the values have been pasted.

Comment: Thankyou @Variatus once again for the code, I just solved the problem running a new macro to copy formatting after running your code.  It worked Perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, StartCell As Long, EndCell As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
            If IsEmpty(.Range("A" & i).Value) Then

                EndCell = i + 1

                LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

                Set rng = .Range("A" & StartCell & ":A" & EndCell)

                rng.Cut .Cells(1, LastColumn + 1)
            Else
                If i = LastRow Or IsEmpty(.Range("A" & i).Offset(1, 0).Value) Then
                    StartCell = i
                End If

            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked perfectly too. Thank you Once again!